# Formatting scientific, with fixed number of decimals

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to mimic Excel's scientific number formatting, preferably with control over the number of decimal places. For example,

1234 ==> would render as ==> 1.23E03 
1234567 ==> would render as ==> 1.23E06 
-1234 ==> would render as ==> -1.23E03

.. and so on.

I see the SI-prefix("s") formatting, but that doesn't let me explicitly control the unit. I have a feeling formatPrefix would let me control this, but I can't quite get it right. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

PS: As an extension to this, I would like to format numbers by specific units. For example, if I select "K" as a unit, then I would get 50k, 500k, 5000k and so on (instead of 5M for the last one).

Comment: D3 doesn't support this, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how I missed this, but the exponent("e") type works to a large extent in D3

> `f =d3.format(".2e")` 
>   `console.log(f(1234))    // 1.23e+3` 
>   `console.log(f(1234567)) // 1.23e+6` 
>   `console.log(f(-1234))   //-1.23e+3`

Lars is correct about the other one. I haven't found anything to support a specific unit (like "K")

Comment: 's' gives you 'K, M' etc.